# Neo4j Docker Connection failure

Tags: python, docker, neo4j, py2neo, neo4j-driver

I am facing the neo4j connection issue while trying the run the neo4j code; the same working fine outside docker but failing to establish the connection with neo4j database while running inside docker.

Error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 835, in _connect
    s.connect(resolved_address)
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=("neo4j", "admin"))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neo4j/__init__.py", line 116, in driver
    return Driver(uri, **config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neo4j/__init__.py", line 157, in __new__
    return subclass(uri, **config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neo4j/__init__.py", line 231, in __new__
    pool.release(pool.acquire())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 719, in acquire
    return self.acquire_direct(self.address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 612, in acquire_direct
    connection = self.connector(address, error_handler=self.connection_error_handler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neo4j/__init__.py", line 228, in connector
    return connect(address, **dict(config, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 976, in connect
    raise last_error
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 966, in connect
    s = _connect(resolved_address, **config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 847, in _connect
    raise ServiceUnavailable("Failed to establish connection to {!r} (reason {})".format(resolved_address, error))
neobolt.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: Failed to establish connection to ('::1', 11010, 0, 0) (reason [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address)
```

The code I used is as follows:

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase
uri = "bolt://localhost:11010/"
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=("neo4j", "admin"))
with driver.session() as session:
    result = session.run("MATCH (n) RETURN count(n)")
    print(result)
    session.close()
```

My bolt port is 11010 as in code. Am I missing anything here? I tried the below things but no luck
1) used 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost
2) closed the sessions

And my docker file is as follows:

```
FROM python:3
ADD test.py /
RUN pip install pandas
RUN pip install pymysql
RUN pip install sqlalchemy
RUN pip install neo4j
CMD ["python","test.py"]
```

Comment: where you running neo4j database?

Comment: Local machine itself and also running docker locally @Adiii

Comment: does this help?

Answer (score 2):

From the comment, I assume the neo4j Database is running in other containers.

You can not connect from one container to another container using URL `localhost`.

Localhost always refers to the localhost of the current container not the other container call it B.

So possible alternate and solution

- IF both are running in two different container use Docker-compose and you will able to access new4j database from container name like `neo4j:port` thats it.
- If new4j running on the host, then you need to access new4j using the **HOST** ip inside your python container.
- If you you do not want to use docker-compose, you can use lagacy `linking`

```
 docker run -d -P --name web --link newdb:db training/webapp python app.py
```

Now you refer it from inside python container like `db` as a host.

Comment: Able to connect MYSQL with such settings but not Neo4j. And Neo4j is on host and I am using the IP to connect. But failing.

Comment: you have to host IP local ip that some thing `192.*.` it should work . and also you can telnet the port of `new4g` from container

Comment: Not just local, I have a Neo4j running in another server. I am using that IP. The same code works fine without dockerising

Comment: then telnet the port of the server or is there every thing right like connection string?

Answer (score 2):

if you're running python inside a container use:

```
    GraphDatabase.driver(host="<contaniner>", auth=basic_auth("neo4j", "myPass"))
```